# Multiple modules folders import

Tags: python, python-3.x

With python 3.10, I have a programm with this kind of structure:

```
.vscode
├── src
│   ├── moduleA
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── mymodA.py
│   ├── moduleB
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── mymodB.py
│   └── main.py
└── test.py
```

My targets :

- Working progamm :)
- Working pytest
- Working coverage

I test multiples ways:

1. First

```py
#main.py
from moduleA.mymodA import funcA
```

```py
#mymodA.py
from moduleB import funcB
```

```py
#test.py
from src.moduleA.mymodA import funcA
```

> Results:
>
> - App : pass
> - pytest : failed with "Test result not found"
> - coverage : failed with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moduleB'"

2. Second

```py
#main.py
from moduleA.mymodA import funcA
```

```py
#mymodA.py
from src.moduleB import funcB
```

```py
#test.py
from src.moduleA.mymodA import funcA
```

> Results:
>
> - App : failed with "No module named 'src'"
> - pytest : pass
> - coverage : pass

I have add in the **init**.py for each module with no change:

```py
#__init__.py
from .moduleA import funcA
```

I have test some other things but no many mor chance.
Did I have to use absolute path like ?

```py
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

foo = SourceFileLoader("module.name", "/path/to/file.py").load_module()
foo.MyClass()
```

If you have any advise for me, thank you :)

Comment: can you paste the command you trigger pytest?

Comment: From root folder :
`py.exe -m pytest -v .\tests\test_moda.py`

Comment: can you try append source root dir to `sys.path`, since this is a very common often used option in ides?

Comment: Thank you Lei, I've added the path of the project in PYTHONPATH, and all is working.